# What would be the correct file extension for a Gist of disassembled Java?

Tags: java, github, jvm, gist

If I want to put something like

```
  public int compareTo(fractions.Fraction);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokevirtual #92 // Method minus:(Lfractions/Fraction;)Lfractions/Fraction;
       5: astore_2
       6: aload_2
       7: getfield      #1 // Field numerator:J
      10: lconst_0
      11: lcmp
      12: ifge          17
      15: iconst_m1
      16: ireturn
      17: aload_2
      18: getfield      #1 // Field numerator:J
      21: lconst_0
      22: lcmp
      23: ifle          28
      26: iconst_1
      27: ireturn
      28: iconst_0
      29: ireturn
```

into a GitHub Gist, what file extension should I use for the Gist? My first instinct was *.java, but that's kind of misleading. So now I'm thinking *.javap.

I did try putting this question to Google, that doesn't seem to have gotten any useful results.

Comment: .txt? It's text and there's is no official extension afaik. Extensions don't really matter though. Why do you care?

Comment: I don't want to invent something different to replace something that already exists.